# Sitecore Changing Template

Tags: inheritance, sitecore, placeholder

I have old template and new template. Both templates have standard value for controls and placeholder key names are different.

But, as shown in the screenshot, manually added controls (not from standard values) in page item (old template) don't reflect in the page item (new template) after changing the old template to new template.

Is it Sitecore's concept or do I need any other settings??
Otherwise, I have to manually update placeholder key and all datasource information for each item (total over 100 page items).

Any solution???

[Click for Big Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7sev.png)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a side effect of how [Layout Deltas](https://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/12/Sitecore-Idiosyncrasies-Layout-Details-and-Layout-Deltas.aspx) in Sitecore work.

When you define presentation in your Template, your setting up a bit of XML that describes the Template's idea of what the set of controls should be. When you then edit the Presentation Details on an Item based on your Template, you're not editing the original definition of the Layout. You're editing a "delta" - a fragment of XML which says what should be different from the Template.

Unfortunately, when you change the template, the delta becomes a bit meaningless.

So you're going to have to do one of the following:

1) If your Template defines exactly what the pages should look like, and the deltas on your page Items aren't relevant any more, then you need to remove these deltas. In this case, you can select a Page and click the "Reset" button for Presentation Details to get rid of the old data:

[image: Reset Presentation Details]
This just gets rid of the layout delta on the current item.

2) If each page does have to be different, then you're going to need to replace the deltas with the correct new information. Which may involve editing all the pages. If you need to process lots of pages using the same rules, you could consider scripting your changes using the [PowerShell extensions for Sitecore](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx)? But if every page is different, then you may just have to do it by hand.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't think the first option is a solution in my situation. This is because if I do "reset", all manually added controls in page item are gone. In this case, I have to add each controls (not assigned in standard values) manually again. It is worse than updating. Otherwise, the second option will be helpful. Thanks again!